# creating a Microsoft.JScript file

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, jscript

I just heard about `Microsoft.Jscript` and I saw its structure and I'm fascinated with it. I'm working with Visual Studio 2012 and ASP.NET MVC 4 and there's no way to find out how do I add or create a file of this type.

Comment: maybe you mean TypeScript?

Comment: no JScript. But well TypeScript is good I saw it and it's great but i want to know about JScript

Comment: then why you can't add it? press right button on some folder in Solution Explorer, Add -> New Item -> JScript

Comment: it just doesn't appear

Answer (score 0):

[Wikipedia JScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JScript#Comparison_to_JavaScript)

> JScript is the Microsoft dialect of the ECMAScript scripting language
>   specification.
>
> JavaScript (the Netscape/Mozilla implementation of the ECMA
>   specification), JScript, and ECMAScript are very similar languages. In
>   fact the name "JavaScript" is often used to refer to ECMAScript or
>   JScript.

In VS2012 there isn't an option for JScript anymore, it is now Javascript. Which both options give you the same thing, an empty file with the .js extension. There are a few differences between Microsofts implementation of ECMAScript (JScript) and other browsers implementation. You also might run into issues if you attempt to link the js file in your site as:

```
<script type="text/jscript" src="myfile.js"></script>
```

OR

```
<script type="JScript" src="myfile.js"></script>
```

instead of:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="myfile.js"></script>
```